# install red5 demos via installer or within war file manually

Tags: deployment, red5

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and installed the red5-server package.
I've also downloaded oflaDemo.war file from [that](http://red5.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3990/snapshots/oflaDemo-r3989-java6.war) address.

First I tried to install the oflaDemo via installer, but I couldnt reach the goal. I see the .war file under the /tmp directory, I got stuck with this message: *"This may take a couple minutes, please wait"*.

After that, I put the downloaded war file into the /webapps directory and wait 10 minutes as mentioned in red5-common.xml. Unfortunately, nothing changed ...

So I decided to extract war file manually. I did this: **jar -xvf oflaDemo.war**

Ok, I see all of the unzipped content under the webapps directory, but how can I preview the demo via a web browser?

I really need to make live stream via Red5. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem. Unzip the content under the webapps folder with theirs name. For example: webapps/oflaDemo -or another name you can understand-. Restart red5 and see all things worked.

You can download all the war files from that address: http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/snapshots/

Only the adminPanel demo has problems. The solution is a little bit tricky. If you google it, you can see the solutions.

Thank you :)